# If a player is optioned out 3 times and brought back 3 times how many options did he use up?

Tags: baseball, mlb

A player was optioned to the minors 3 times and brought back 3 times. How many options did he burn?

Comment: Depends on a lot of specifics.  How many days is he with the minor league team?  When did the stints happen (during one season?  three separate seasons?).   https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5337/how-does-optioning-a-player-to-the-minor-leagues-work?rq=1 has a lot of info.

Comment: That said, this did change this year, so if you can clarify the questions BowlOfRed asked, it is worth answering this anew I think.